When doing a t-test, should sample standard deviation be estimated by subtracting the sample mean or the null hypothesis' mean?
Take the example of a t-test to test if a sample of real numbers $x_i$ come from a distribution with mean 0 ($H_0: \mu=0, H_a: \mu \neq 0$). The test statistic would be $t=\frac{\bar{x}}{s/\sqrt{n}}$.
My question asks if $s^2=\frac{\sum_i(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{n-1}$ or $s^2=\frac{\sum_i x_i^2}{n}$.
In most texts I see the former, but in the context of financial data I sometimes see the latter. Both also seem to make sense, where the former uses the normal sample standard deviation formula and the latter uses the null hypothesis and also no longer needs Bessel's correction.
What are the pros and cons of both, and is any method more proper?
EDIT: To summarize, it looks like with proper treatment to get the quantiles for either test statistic, the tests are equivalent. But only the former follows the t-distribution. In the end, they both asymptotically approach the same thing.

Sample mean. The null plays no part in the estimate of the sample standard deviation.

It's a question of power.  Intuitively, under the null hypothesis the second expression will be inflated (by an amount proportional to $(\bar x)^2$) which reduces the test statistic (making it more difficult to reject the null) as well as changing the distribution of the test statistic to a non-central t distribution with unknown mean.  Neither change helps you!

@whuber The two tests turns out to be equivalent (although the alternative test statistic is of course not Student T under $H_0$).

@Jarle In what sense, then, are the tests "equivalent"?

Since the non-standard statistic $T'=g(T)$ where $g$ is strictly increasing, the critical value of the non standard test would be $g(t_{\alpha/2,n-1})$ and the event that $H_0$ is rejected would be $T'>g(t_{\alpha/2,n-1})$ equivalent to the event $T>t_{\alpha/2,n-1}$ that $H_0$ is rejected by the standard test.

@Jarle Thank you for being explicit about that.  In other words, provided one uses the correct reference distribution -- which is different from the one implied by calling this a t-test! -- the p-value will be the same.

The alternative test statistic you propose based on the MLE of $\sigma$ under $H_0$ turns out to be a strictly increasing function of the standard $t$-statistic (as illustrated below for $n=10$).  This is easy to prove algebraically. Therefore, a test based on your alternative statistic would be equivalent to the classical $t$-test.
You would probably not want to use the alternative statistic in practice, however, since it has a somewhat awkward distribution under $H_0$.
n <- 10
tt <- replicate(1e+3, {
  x <- rnorm(n)
  t <- t.test(x)$stat
  t_alt <- mean(x)/sqrt(mean(x^2))*sqrt(n)
  c(t,t_alt)
})
plot(t(tt), xlab="Standard statistic", ylab="Alternative statistic")


Created on 2024-09-06 with reprex v2.1.0

From an asymptotic viewpoint, the nonstandard version should be "fine", though? It uses a consistent estimator of the variance under the null, so yields an asymptotic N(0,1) distribution.

The tests are always equivalent.  The critical value of the non-standard statistic would not be a student $t$ quantile however, so I don't think your power computations are correct.  If using the correct critical values, the power of either test would also be equivalent.

Hm, fair point - I now replace them with what I argue are asymptotically correct critical values (with similar results as before, but then, plausibly, once more power curves that do not agree fully).

@ChristophHanck I disagree, you can find the exact critical values via some algebra, see my above comment to whuber.

Disagree with what? I do not dispute that the exact critical values can be found - I just did not do it and instead give an example with critical values from an asymptotic distribution (that would moreover be "correct" for other population distributions than the normal).

Here is a little simulation (with "asymptotic" critical values from the N(0,1) distribution) to illustrate. In this case, unlike in Jarle's argument, the tests then are not equivalent, but the power of the two tests is fairly close:

mu.0 <- 0
mu <- 0
n <- 50

t.stats <- function(n, mu) {
  x <- rnorm(n, mean = mu)
  t.conventional <- sqrt(n)*(mean(x)-mu.0)/sd(x)
  t.null <- sqrt(n)*(mean(x)-mu.0)/sqrt(mean(x^2))
  return(c(t.conventional, t.null))
}

statistics <- replicate(10000, t.stats(n, mu))
plot(density(statistics[1,]), lwd=2, col="magenta", xlim=c(-4,4))
xax <- seq(-4, 4, by=.01)
lines(xax, dt(xax, n-1), col="darkgreen", lwd=2)
lines(density(statistics[2,]), lwd=2, col="darkblue")

power.func <- function(n, mu){
  statistics <- replicate(10000, t.stats(n, mu))
  pow.t.conv <- mean(abs(statistics[1,]) > qnorm(.975))
  pow.t.null <- mean(abs(statistics[2,]) > qnorm(.975))
  power <- c(pow.t.conv, pow.t.null)
}

mus <- seq(0, 0.8, 0.05)
power <- sapply(mus, function(m) power.func(n, m))
matplot(mus, t(power), type="l", lwd=2)

